# php exec c program in background error

Tags: php, c, command-line, background, exec

I'm trying to execute a program in the background using php. The c program is this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("hello\n");
    int i =0;
    printf("hello world\n");
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/gianpaolo/workspace/test/outputfile", "w+");

    while(i < 60000000) {
        fprintf(fp, "hello world\n");
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and the php that runs the program goes like this

```
<?php
$out = array();
exec('/home/gianpaolo/workspace/test/test 2>&1', $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

I'm triggering this code using a webpage that has a reference to this code. As you can see I'm printing the variable $out to see what's happening and this is what i get

```
 Array ( [0] => Segmentation fault )
```

If I run any command line it works great but if I run this it won't any ideas?

---UPDATE---
I checked as suggested if the fp was NULL which in fact it was. So, how can I grant permission so it can open to write or create to write files?

Comment: look into chmod or chown for permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of your `fopen` call.

I guess that the user which runs the webserver hasn't got enough permissions to write (or even read) the file. If that's the case, `fopen` will return a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: I though of it but as you can see in the c code there's a printf before the fopen that's not been outputed

Comment: I checked if fp was NULL and in fact it was. Now is there a way to grant permission to open/create files

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because of 2 things

1. You don't check for failure to open file (i.e. `fp` is null)
2. Your web server user (usually www-data or similar) does not have the permissions to open that file

combine those two and you are trying to write to a file you (www-data in this case) don't have permissions to and thus using a `NULL` pointer in the `fwrite` call in the C program, dereferencing a `NULL` pointer in the `fwrite` call causes a segfault

In short, remember your web server does not run as the same user, with the same permissions as you.

**Edit:** You will want to use the `chmod` shell command to grant read & write permissions on the directory to "other" (unless you don't want to let anyone write there, just www-data, in which case you'll need to use `chown` as well. Strictly speaking this part of the question lives on http://serverfault.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: You were right, is there a way to give permission so it can open/create files?

Comment: `man chmod` should be enough to get you started with the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether fp was NULL when it returned from fopen? As stated [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/):

> If the file has been succesfully
>   opened the function will return a
>   pointer to a FILE object that is used
>   to identify the stream on all further
>   operations involving it. **Otherwise, a
>   null pointer is returned.**